# 「img.onload」後に、生成したimgオブジェクトを「img.style.display = 'none';」している理由は？

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

**リンク先の「カラーピッカー」で、「img.onload」後に、「img.style.display = 'none';」しているのですが、どういう意味があるでしょうか？**
・コメントアウトしても挙動は同じでした

**「display = 'none';」でも、画像は非表示にならないのは…**
・canvasに描画したから、imgは不要ということでしょうか？
・imgオブジェクトは、生成しただけなので(DOMに組み込んでいないので)、わざわざ非表示にする必要もないように思うのですが…
・削除ではなく非表示？？

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
img.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  img.style.display = 'none';
};
```

[mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問者さんもおっしゃってる通り私も理由思い付かず、意味はないと思います。

Comment: もしかして深い意味があるのでは？　と思い質問したのですが…。なるほど、参考になりました